# How to show Progress Dialog with percentage while accessing Firebase Firestore data

Tags: android, progressdialog

Can anyone please help to get the code for showing percentage in Progress dialog box while accessing data from firebase firestore.

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: I have shown the Progress dialog box and dismised, but I want to show the processing % like how we see in file download in chrome